# Query passar parâmetro null, trazendo todos os valores

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá,

Tenho uma consulta na qual preciso que me traga ou o valor passado no parâmetro ou, caso não seja informado nenhum valor, trazer todas as informações que não sejam nulas:

Exemplo

```
select cd_medicamento, nm_medicamento, via_aplicacao, cd_grupo_medicamento
from medicamentos
where cd_grupo_materiais = :cd_grupo_materiais
and via_aplicacao = :via_aplicacao
```

Nesse caso, preciso que traga todos os materiais de um determinado grupo de materiais e com uma determinada via de aplicação, mas caso não seja inserida nenhuma informação em via de aplicação, preciso que me retorne todos os materiais desse grupo de materiais que tenham um valor registrado. Tentei das duas formas abaixo e não funcionou:

```
select cd_medicamento, nm_medicamento, via_aplicacao, cd_grupo_medicamento
from medicamentos
where cd_grupo_materiais = :cd_grupo_materiais
and ((via_aplicacao = :via_aplicacao) or (via_aplicacao is not null))

select cd_medicamento, nm_medicamento, via_aplicacao, cd_grupo_medicamento
from medicamentos
where cd_grupo_materiais = :cd_grupo_materiais
and case when :via_aplicacao is null
then via_aplicacao is not null
else via_aplicacao = :via_aplicacao
end
```

O campo via_aplicacao recebe um varchar2
No primeiro exemplo, a query me retorna sempre todos os valores da tabela, mesmo passando parâmetro específico para a via de aplicação.
No segundo exemplo não me retorna nada

Comment: costumo fazer nvl(trim(:param_campox)),campox) = campox